# How to pass multiple args to a rust closure - expected closure that takes 1 argument

Tags: rust

I am new to closures and I don't understand why I am getting the following error.

If I don't include the second argument its works:

```
fn obj_x(x: Vec<f64>) -> f64 {
    return 0.0;
};

let f = |x: &Vec<f64>| obj_x(x.to_vec());
```

Here is my closure:

```
fn foo() {
    let f = |x: &Vec<f64>, N: usize| obj_x(x.to_vec(), N);
}

fn obj_x(x: Vec<f64>, N: usize) -> f64 {
    let x = (x[0] + 4.0).powf(2.0);

    return x;
}
```

But unfortunately it fails

```
error[E0593]: closure is expected to take 1 argument, but it takes 2 arguments
   --> src/main.rs:120:44
    |
114 |     let f = |x: &Vec<f64>, N: usize | obj_x(x.to_vec(),N);
    |             ------------------------- takes 2 arguments
...
120 |         let mut fmin = Funcmin::new(&mut x,&f,&g,"cg");
    |                                            ^^ expected closure that takes 1 argument
    |
```

Here is my full code:

```
fn obj_x(x: Vec<f64>, N: usize) -> f64 {
    let x = (x[0] + 4.0).powf(2.0);

    return x;
}

fn gradient_x(x: Vec<f64>) -> Vec<f64> {
    return vec![2.0 * (x[0] + 4.0)];
}

fn test() {
    let f = |x: &Vec<f64>, &N: usize| obj_x(x.to_vec(), N);
    let g = |x: &Vec<f64>| gradient_x(x.to_vec());
    let mut x = vec![40.0f64];
    let mut N = 2220;
    {
        //you must create a mutable object
        let mut fmin = Funcmin::new(&mut x, &f, &g, "cg");
        fmin.minimize();
    }
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

Comment: What is `Funcmin`? The problem seems to be in there. Is it from here - https://github.com/noshu/rustimization?

Comment: Yes from there I am trying to extend their logic because I need to pass more args

Comment: And how `Funcmin` is suppose to know what to give as second argument to your function ?!? If `N` is not an argument but a constant, just capture it in the closure. Also, you should read the book.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me: declare

`fn fold(n: u32, init: u32, op: impl Fn(u32, u32) -> u32) -> u32 {...`

and call it as

`fold(n, 1, |x: u32, y: u32| -> u32 {x + y })`